# Why do you not have to initialize a set when using set = map.entryset();

Tags: java, initialization

How can you add a map to a set without initializing a set or setting it to a HashSet or a TreeSet?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     HashMap<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap<>();
     hMap.put(0,"a");
     Set set = hMap.entrySet();
     System.out.println(set);
 }
```

Comment: Why does the line Set set = hMap.entrysSet(); work? Should you not add the map to a set after you initialize the set like Set<> set = new Set<>();

Comment: The entrySet() method is used to get a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_entryset The answer is that you initialize the Set with map.entryset()

Comment: Well, by definition? Do the docs help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet-- ?

Comment: Looking at your other questions: I really recommend you to find a good Java book/course. It'll give you much more complete knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> How can you add a map to a set without initializing a set or setting
>   it to a hashset or a treeset?

The short answer is that you're not "adding a map to a set".

You are requesting the map give you a view of the map contents as they exist in the map.  You get a reference to a Set<> that exists 'within the map' in some sense (we know it's not just a one-time copy because the documentation tells us that modifying the returned set will modify the map, and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

Consider this dummy statement. It initializes the `obj` variable of type Object with a `new` Object using the `new` keyword. Basically, the purpose of the RHS is to provide the variable in the LHS with a compatible `java object`.

Which means it is not necessary to always initialize a variable using `new` keyword. In this case, the map.entrySet() is a method defined inside the *HashMap or TreeMap or LinkedHashMap* class which returns an object of `Set` type and that is how the `Set` is initialized with that object.

A simple example would be:

```
int x = getValue();

static int getValue() {
    return 5;
}
```

After running this, the value of `x` will be 5. Now, `int` is a primitive type, but the same goes for Objects, just like your example.